# flash as3 - can't get loaded image to attach to the proper location on the stage

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, loader

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this code:

```
for (var k=0;k<2;k++){
    var thumb_cols:int = 9;
    var thumb_spacing:int = 10; //spaces the clips
    project_thumbs_list[k] = myXML.projects.project[k].@thumb;
    var projectThumb:thumbClip = new thumbClip();
    projectThumb.thumbTitle.text = myXML.projects.project[k].title.toUpperCase();
    projectThumb.x = (projectThumb.width + thumb_spacing) * (k % thumb_cols);
    projectThumb.y = (projectThumb.width + thumb_spacing) * int(k / thumb_cols);
    project_thumbs_array[k] = projectThumb;
    var thumbLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(myXML.projects.project[k].@thumb));
    thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
}

function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
    project_thumbs_array[currentLoaded].thumbHolder.addChild(thumbLoader);
    admin.slideHolder.addChild(project_thumbs_array[currentLoaded]);
    currentLoaded++;
}
```

I have a sample XML file with two images. If I remove either of the items from the XML, it everything displays fine, but with 2 items in the XML, the first item doesn't show an image, but the second does (maybe the first is being attached in a position behind the second?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
project_thumbs_array[currentLoaded].thumbHolder.addChild(thumbLoader);
```

to:

```
project_thumbs_array[currentLoaded].thumbHolder.addChild(e.target.data);
```

might be e.target.content  I can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: awesome! Yeah - it's e.target.content - I can never remember how they reference that thing.

Comment: me neither lol.  I always check a previous project to remember.  Glad it worked.  :)  I remember now:  .data is for URLLoader, for loading XML and such..

Answer (score 0):

This *should* give you 10 pixel horizontal spacing between entities.  I didn't address the y-value, but I would recommend taking a look at that as well.

```
var x_counter = 10;
for (var k=0;k<2;k++){
    var thumb_cols:int = 9;
    var thumb_spacing:int = 10; //spaces the clips
    project_thumbs_list[k] = myXML.projects.project[k].@thumb;
    var projectThumb:thumbClip = new thumbClip();
    projectThumb.thumbTitle.text = myXML.projects.project[k].title.toUpperCase();
    projectThumb.x = x_counter;
    projectThumb.y = (projectThumb.width + thumb_spacing);
    x_counter = x_counter + projectThumb.width + thumb_spacing;
    project_thumbs_array[k] = projectThumb;
    var thumbLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    thumbLoader.load(new URLRequest(myXML.projects.project[k].@thumb));
    thumbLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
}
```